# Python How to check presence of a column in dataframe by it's name or number

Tags: python, pandas, design-patterns

I have written a function which asks a user for column name (ex. 'Age') or column number (0, 1, ... or -1, -2, ...) and returns it if exists. I would like to know if my solution can be improved in terms of code design.

To clarify, I need this piece of code for another function which calculates Shannon Entropy on the dataframes for which label-column should be chosen manually.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B':['a', 'b', 'c']})

def read(df):
    while True:
        column = input("Please, enter column name or number:") 
        if column.lstrip('-').isdecimal():
            if (-df.shape[1] > int(column)) or (int(column) >= df.shape[1]):
                print('Such column does not exist. Please, try again. \n')
                continue
            else:
                return df.iloc[:, int(column)]
        elif column not in df.columns:
            print('Such column does not exist. Please, try again. \n')
            continue
        else:
            return df.loc[:, column]
    return data[column]

read(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns are available in `df.columns` which can be used to get the data you want. If the column isn't in `df.columns`, try converting it  to an `int` to index `df.columns` and use an exception handler to deal with the misses.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B':['a', 'b', 'c']})

def read(df):
    while True:
        column = input("Please, enter column name or number:")
        if column not in df.columns:
            try:
                column = df.columns[int(column)]
            except (IndexError, ValueError):
                print(f"Column {column!r} does not exist, Please try again.")
                continue
        break
    return df.loc[:, column]

print(read(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach would say that we should try to select from the DataFrame and handle the errors that arise, since `pandas` has already done a lot of work to see whether or not an indexer is valid:

If we go fully in this direction, we end up with something like:

```
def read(df_: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    while True:
        column = input("Please, enter column name or number:")
        try:
            # Attempt to return the Column
            return df_[column]
        except KeyError:
            try:
                # Attempt to convert the column to int and return the column
                return df_.iloc[:, int(column)]
            except (ValueError, IndexError):
                # Print Message if both attempts fail
                print('Such column does not exist. Please, try again. \n')
```

I've changed the function parameter from `df` to `df_` to avoid shadowing a variable from an external scope.

We first read in the column, then attempt to return the subset DataFrame. This raises a `KeyError` if it does not exist in the `DataFrame`. In this case, we attempt to access the values positionally. `int(column)` will raise a `ValueError` if it cannot be converted to an `int`, and `iloc` will produce an `IndexError` if the indexer is out of bounds.

---

A slightly modified version of this is:

```
def read(df_: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    while True:
        try:
            column = input("Please, enter column name or number:")
            try:
                # Try to get int indexer from df_.columns
                indexer = df_.columns.get_loc(column)
            except KeyError:
                # Use int version of Column
                indexer = int(column)
            return df_.iloc[:, indexer]
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            # Catch Invalid int conversion, or out of bounds indexes
            print('Such column does not exist. Please, try again. \n')
```

Here we use [`Index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) which "Get integer location, slice or boolean mask for requested label." This also raises a `KeyError` if the label is not present in columns, however, in this case we attempt to convert `column` to `indexer` in the `except`.

This means that `indexer` is guaranteed to be integer location based and can be passed to `iloc`. Then we can except the `ValueError` caused if the `int` conversion fails, and the `IndexError` which occurs if the indexer is out of bounds.